# I need to get the Messages app on OS X Lion (10.7)

Tags: macos, messages, mac-mini, imovie

I would like to start by stating that I am new to this forum, and have never used it before. Patience is appreciated!
All greetings aside, I need help with my Mac Mini.
I have an early 2007 Mac mini that I have running OS X Lion. (the latest version that it supports) I believe that this system is 64 bit, as per this post: [is my mac 64 bit or 32 bit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12666/how-to-check-whether-my-intel-based-mac-is-32-bit-or-64-bit%20%22Is%20My%20Mac%2064%20or%2032%20bit?)

The point of this is, I need this Mac to run iMovie 11, as well as the Messages application. Now, I would prefer to stick with Lion, execpt, I truly wouldn't mind 'hacking' this system to run something like Yosemite or El Capitan, because I am thinking of doing this in the near future.

Finally, one more thing. As per the guide I quoted above, I think this mini is 64 bit. The problem is, all of the "run Yosemite" or "Run El Capitan" on unsupported macs all make the use of SFOTT. (sixty four on thirty two)

I have tried the Messages beta app, which apparently is no longer supported, (no suprise there!) and would truly appreciate fast responses to this thread.

Here's a screenshot of the specs on my mini:
[image: mac mini specs]

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to jump around quite a bit and because of that is a little confusing. Below are some answers that may help.

1. If you want to confirm whether your Mac Mini is 64 bit, the answer is **yes**.
2. Your question title says *I need to get the Messages app on OS X Lion (10.7)* but your question details say you already have the Messages beta app installed. That is the only official version (albeit in *beta*) that was released for Mac OS X Lion. In other words you already have Messages installed, so I'm not sure what you're question title is about?
3. Your question also states *I need this Mac to run iMovie 11*. iMovie '11 was bundled with all new Macs sold on or after October 20, 2010 or for separate purchase in iLife '11. So, if you want it installed on your Mac Mini, you would have had to have purchased and installed it (as part of iLife '11). It was also available for purchase on the Mac App Store. The good news is that in terms of compatibility, iMovie '11 works perfectly in Mac OS X Lion (10.7).

If what you want to know is something different, then please clarify your question.

Comment: I do not need iMovie at this point. Messages beta does not work on this mac, I just need to use messages on this computer. Even if it means some type of hacking :)